# MongoDB .NET driver find all : How to write it better?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am able to  query all the items of a collection using 2 approaches

a)

```
var findAll = await Context.ItemsCollection.FindAsync(_ => true);
var res = await findAll.ToListAsync();
```

b)

```
var res = await.Context.ItemsCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
```

Is there a real difference between them?Which one should I prefer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference. It will eventually behave the same.

`Find` doesn't execute the query, while `FindAsync` does, but using `ToListAsync` makes that difference irrelevant.